# Is is possible to have Selectize not dropdown until there are 3 chars entered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I am using `Selectize` to search a large set of data that I have in an array locally.

When the user clicks on the Selectize element, it opens right then and tries to show the full list.  This is some `3000` items that have to go through my custom render right then.

I would rather that the user has to enter at least 3 chars then show what matches.

I know that there is a `"maxOptions"` setting, but that still shows the dropdown when the user clicks in.  Which is confusing to them, because now I am showing only `100` of the `3000` options.

If possible, I would also like it to not show the dropdown once an option has been selected (this is for `maxItems = 1`).

Note: I tried to use `openOnFocus=false` to try to do this, but it seems to only stop the first click from opening the dropdown.

**Any ideas on how I can keep Selectize from opening unless the user is typing in a search?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the 'open' function and got this to work.

I added this line after the first line:

```
var value = self.$control_input.val();
```

I then added `value.length < 3` to the list of checks that cause the open to be ignored.

Works perfectly.  I have to say that this code is some of the cleanest 3rd party javascript code I have had the pleasure to work with.

Comment: you modified library function `open`?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam - I added the Selectize library to my project.  And I modified the `open` method in my of the code.  (I actually added a `openOnlyAfterNumberOfChars` option to it, not the hard coded number example in my answer.)  (I was careful to document this in a separate file so later updates can re-apply it, though it seems that Selectize is out of routine maintenance.)

Comment: hmmm... why not use `remote` source rather than going for this approach.why not show only the relevant options to the search keywords

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam - remote data takes a while to get.  It is much faster if I have already downloaded it.  My app is such that a single download on startup is better than running to the server for each search.

Answer (score 1):

the official [examples](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/examples/create-filter.html) have one of these see the demo below, hope this is what you were looking for

```js
$('#select-words-length').selectize({
  create: true,
  createFilter: function(input) {
    return input.length >= parseInt($('#length').val(), 10);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.4/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.4/css/selectize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="wrapper">
  <h1>Selectize.js</h1>
  <div class="demo">
    <h2>Create Filter</h2>
    <p>Examples of how to filter created results.</p>

    <div class="control-group" style="margin-top:40px">
      <label for="length">Minimum Length</label>
      <input type="text" id="length" value="2"><br><br>
      <label for="select-words-length">Words:</label>
      <select id="select-words-length" multiple placeholder="Enter a word longer than the minimum number of characters..."></select>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  However, from what I see, this is a way to have a min length for adding a result to the drop down options.  Not to limit opening the dropdown when there are already options existing.

Comment: so you are pre-populating the menu with all the options rather than searching and the filtering them using `remote` source ? @Vaccano

Comment: Yes.  Getting the data takes some time, so I get it in advance then set the selectize `options` option to my array.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying open() in the library per OP's own answer did the trick to prevent the dropdown from opening before the desired number of characters.  However, if the user hits backspace to shorten the search term, the dropdown remains open.
To fix this, modify the switch statement in the onKeyDown() function:

```
case KEY_BACKSPACE:
  if (self.isOpen) {
    self.close();
  }
  return;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var no_of_char = 1;

function temp() {
  var $select = $(document.getElementById('model-select')).selectize({

    // ...
    // ...
    // ...

    openOnFocus: false
  });
  var selectize = $select[0].selectize;

  selectize.on('type', function(e) {
    if (selectize.$control_input.val().length < no_of_char) {
      selectize.close();
    }
  });
}

temp();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/js/selectize.js"></script>
<link href="https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/css/selectize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="main">
  <select id="model-select">
    <option></option>
    <option value="0">abc</option>
    <option value="1">abcxyz</option>
    <option value="2">abcmno</option>
    <option value="3">abcpqr</option>
  </select>
  <br>
</div>
```